# Calculate attributes from a class using js

Tags: javascript, class, attributes

Im trying to make a function that allows me to calculate the price of the games sold. So far i've made this but i dont know what im doing wrong.

```
class games {
    constructor(Name, Price, Quantity) {
      this.Name = Name ;
      this.Price = Price ;
      this.Quantity = Quantity;
    }
  }
let game1 = new games('call of duty', 50, 15)
let game2 = new games('NBA2k', 60, 19)

function calculate() {
  this.Price*this.Quantity
}
console.log(calculate())
```

Comment: It is best practice for class names to follow Pascal Case: https://techterms.com/definition/pascalcase. Similarly, properties of a class should follow Camel Case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the function in the class:

```
class Games {
  constructor(Name, Price, Quantity, quantitysold) {
    this.Name = Name ;
    this.Price = Price ;
    this.Quantity = Quantity;
  }
  calculate() {
    return this.Price * this.Quantity
  }
};
let game1 = new Games('call of duty', 50, 15);
let game2 = new Games('NBA2k', 60, 19);

console.log(game1.calculate());
console.log(game2.calculate());
```

Comment: sure, use `console.log(game1.calculate() + game2.calculate())` to get them added together or have them separately like: `console.log(game1.calculate(), game2.calculate())`.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor needs the same amount of passed arguments to get triggered. In your case your constructor needs 4 arguments but you only passes 3. Therefore the constructor wont get triggered.

Comment: thank you for your response but ive also tried with out the 4. one.